# Is there any way to vault over an obstacle without taking cover first?

Tags: mass-effect-2

When I'm running through an area that necessitates several vaults because it's narrow and blocked off by waist high objects, it's kind of annoying to have to slide into cover before *every single obstacle*.

Is there any way to vault/jump over these without having to slide into cover first? Am I missing something, or is this the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't another way. In order to vault over an object you must take cover first.

Mass Effect isn't the first series to do this - the Gears of Wars series works in the same way.

Comment: Uuuugh. Well, at least I know.

Comment: Tapping A/X/space (I think that's the default on PC) as soon as you start entering cover will speed things up, but you will fully enter cover before vaulting.